# Is pylint safe to run on untrusted input?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, sandbox, pylint

Is `pylint` safe to run on untrusted Python code? Classic *static* code analyzers should be safe as they are not executing the code but I don't know how pylint is implemented or any history in this area.

I see there's at least one optional feature, [unsafe-load-any-extension](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html), which makes it unsafe but this is very clearly named to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

It is a static code checker.

From their FAQ page (https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html):

> 1.1 What is Pylint?
>
> Pylint is a **static code checker**, meaning it can analyse your code
>   without actually running it. Pylint checks for errors, tries to
>   enforce a coding standard, and tries to enforce a coding style